# Types of Index in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What are the type of indexes in oracle? How to identify the index need to create?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oracle Database provides several indexing schemes that provide complementary performance functionality. These are:

> - B-tree indexes: the default and the
>   most common

- B-tree cluster indexes: defined
  specifically for cluster
- Hash cluster indexes: defined
  specifically for a hash cluster
- Global and local indexes: relate to
  partitioned tables and indexes
- Reverse key indexes: most useful for
  Oracle Real Application Clusters
  applications
- Bitmap indexes: compact; work best
  for columns with a small set of
  values
- Function-based indexes: contain the
  precomputed value of a
  function/expression
- Domain indexes:
  specific to an application or
  cartridge.

Source:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/indexes.htm

Comment: If you find material for your answer elsewhere on the internet, please give credit to your source.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of index types in Oracle, depending on what object you need to index:

For heap tables, there are **b-tree** indexes and **bitmap** indexes.

A b-tree index is suitable for most applications; bitmap indexes have their own advantages and disadvantages.

There are also specialised indexes for specific data types, using Oracle cartridges; e.g. **Oracle Text** indexes, **spatial** indexes, and 3rd party indexes.

Furthermore, an index might be differentiated by other factors:

- an index on a partitioned table might be global or local
- an index might consist of one column, or multiple columns
- an index might be on a normal column, or on an expression (aka "function-based" index)

For more info, read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/indexiot.htm#BABHJAJF).

An excellent place to find out more than you'll ever want to know about Oracle indexes is [Richard Foote's blog](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/).