# Looking for data in a table through colums with categories/state values

Tags: database, performance, oracle, indexing, partitioning

Say we have a fruits that that is having a high number of reads but also inserts though almost not update nor delete.

We have 2 columns that stores values that have a small number of options. Lets say categories[Banana, apple, orange or pear] and status[finished, ongoing, spoiled, destroyed or ok].
Finally, we have a column last name of owner.

Notes:
I am going to searchs sometimes by category and other by status. 
In all cases, lastname will be used for the search.
I will always perform exact match on categories/status but start with in last name.
Ex of common queries:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit_table WHERE category='BANANA' and last_name LIKE 'Cool%'
SELECT * FROM fruit_table WHERE status='Spoiled'  and last_name LIKE 'Co%'
SELECT * FROM fruit_table WHERE category='BANANA' and last_name LIKE 'smith%'
```

How can I prepare it so we have low response time? 
Will a index help(taking into account that the values in the column are not disperse at all)?
Might bitmap index help here?  
What about partitioning?

Finally, Apologies about the title, I did not know how to formulate it properly.

Comment: Bitmap indexes should generally be avoided in operational environments - they're best suited to datawarehouses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bitmap indexes help immensely with items that have a limited number
  of available choices.
- A standard b-tree index (or non-clustered in SQL Server) will work well
  for the last_name column.
  I would do those two first, as they are easy and then see how things work.

It is generally a bad practice to prematurely optimize.  However, adding indices is quick way to increase speed without much effort.  For more information on indices in Oracle, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460399/types-of-index-in-oracle).